# Кеширование собственного компанента 1C-Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

В файле `.parameters.php`
Есть такой фрагмент кода для подключения кеша.

```
"CACHE_TIME"  =>  array("DEFAULT"=>36000000),
```

При обновлении страницы показывает 22 запроса, после повторного обновления страницы показывает уже 8 запросов. Я так понимаю что этот компонент не закеширован! 22 запроса откуда ? если у меня всего передается своих 5 параметров! Как можно сделать правильную настройку кеша для компонента?

Comment: кто показывает? какие запросы? к чему запросу? Вы на что смотрите? На кол-во SQL-запросов на странице? Так из них нужно отсекать те которые касаются панели админки. Если интересуют те которые касаются только вашего компонента, то сидите и смотрите вручную какие лишние и считайте. Для правильной настройки кеша читайте документацию, хотя бы это - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04780

Comment: Если компонент самописный, смотрите здесь: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3053&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565.4790.4777.3053